# Sharing session via web request

Tags: asp.net, session

I have spend a lot of time on this problem without any change :

I have got 2 simples apsx page, in the first page the

`Page_Load` event put data in the `session` ;

later the on_click event of a button fire an HttpWebRequest  to the second
page

with the idea to retrieve on the page_load of the second page the data in
the session.

to sum up : 1st page put data in session, make the httpWebRequest to the 2nd
page

2nd page : try to get the stored data in the session.

This is the different attempt of code i 've tested to perform this action,
the result was always the same. When i try to add sessionId Information (via
a cookieContainer or directly in the Header request) i get a timeout exception
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() and when i do the HttpWebrequest
without the session_id information i get the response immediatly but without
the session info :-)

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to do this. What's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but have you considered using `Server.Execute` instead?

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2004/Jun/08/Capturing-Output-from-ASPNet-Pages